# Define lists with least fixed point, sum, and product types

Tags: haskell, type-theory, fixpoint-combinators

I want to define lists using only this type definitions:

```
data Unit = Unit
data Prod a b = P a b
data Sum a b = L a | R b
newtype Mu f = Mu (forall a . (f a -> a) -> a)
```

I succeeded defining natural numbers as follows:

```
zeroMu = Mu $ \f -> f $ L Unit
succMu (Mu g) = Mu $ \f -> f $ R $ g f
```

I know how to define lists with the help of an extra data type:

```
data ListF a x = NilF | ConsF a x
nilMu' = Mu $ \f -> f $ NilF
consMu' x (Mu g) = Mu $ \f -> f $ ConsF x $ g f
```

The 'better' I can get is this, but it does not type-checks (intended type is µL.(1+(a*L))):

```
nilMu = Mu $ \f -> f $ L Unit
consMu x (Mu g) = Mu $ \f -> f $ R $ P x $ g f
```

How can I define `nilMu` and `consMu` using only previously defined types and their constructors?

**Edit**

As @chi answer explains, it can be done defining a `newtype` as follows:

```
newtype F a x = F (Sum Unit (Prod a x))
nilMu = Mu $ \f -> f $ F $ L Unit
consMu x (Mu g) = Mu $ \f -> f $ F $ R $ P x $ g f
```

It type-checks, but requires to define a new type.

The intend of this question is to extend a simply typed combinatory logic with unit, product, sum, and recursive types. First three types are straightforward to implement introducing 7 new combinators (`unit`, `pair`, `first`, `second`, `left`, `right`, `case`). Recursive types seems easy to implement too, just add a type constructor combinator `mu`, but as this questoins shows is not flexible enough without additional language constructs.

Is there a solution to this problem? Are there combinatory logics with recursive types to consult?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50911735/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/93207/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: You might try defining [SKI combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) at the type level, which would allow you to express the type level function without a dedicated newtype.  Fun to play with, but it gets very messy.

Comment: @luqui But if you are able to do that it means that type checking is not decidable. My goal in restricting myself to such a weak type theory is to get fully inferred types, so I don't need to add type definitions nor declarations and programs are simple strings of composed combinators without type declarations nor signatures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do it without an additional `data` or `newtype`, in Haskell.

To do it, one would need to write

```
nilMu :: Mu (\l -> S (P a l) ())
consMu :: a -> Mu (\l -> S (P a l) ()) -> Mu (\l -> S (P a l) ())
```

but Haskell does not allow type-level functions in this way. `Mu` can only be applied to a type constructor of kind `* -> *`, not a type-level function of the same kind.

```
nilMu :: Mu (F a)
consMu :: a -> Mu (F a) -> Mu (F a)
```

where `F a` is defined as an additional type

```
newtype F a x = F (S (P a x) ())
```

---

For the reason why Haskell does not allow type level functions, consider

```
assuming foo :: f a -> f Char
infer    foo True :: ???
```

One might argue that in `foo True`, `True` is a `Bool`, so we can infer `f = \t->t` and `a = Bool`. The result is `foo True :: (\t->t) Char = Char`.

One might also argue that we can infer `f = \t->Bool` and `a = String`, and that the result is `foo True :: (\t->Bool) Char = Bool`

In general, we do not like that. We want type inference to proceed by pattern matching `f` and `a` against the actual type. For that, we want both `f` and `a` to have a correspondent "obvious" *name* in the actual type.

For what it is worth, you *can* do this in dependently type languages, such as Coq, Agda, Idris, etc. There, type inference will not work on code like `foo True` above, since `f` can not be inferred. Worse, in these languages, if `bar ::  f a -> ...` and we call `bar [True]`, then `f` could fail to be inferred to `[]` because this is not the only solution (they do have good heuristics, though, which often work anyway, even if the general problem is undecidable).

Comment: Are type level functions the only way? They are an overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user3368561 The answer states that you *cannot* use type-level functions. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @AJFarmar Not in (current) Haskell, yes, but my question is more general and isn't strictly linked to it. I have no problem problem with theoretical answers.

Comment: @user3368561 Well, how would you type `nilMu :: Mu ??` without a type level function?

Comment: Another angle on why Haskell doesn’t allow type-level functions (and therefore also doesn’t allow partially applied type synonyms) is that it would make higher-kinded polymorphism require higher-order unification to solve, which is not decidable in general; as it is, given `a x ~ b y`, the compiler can always deduce `a ~ b` and `x ~ y`, which is very convenient for both programmer reasoning and compiler performance.